# Show div based on getDay and getHours + getMinutes

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I am building a website for a radio station and want to show which presenter is currently on air. I have built a web app that contains data on the presenter: name, photo, bio and start/end times for each weekday.

```
<div id="presenter1">
    <div class="slot">
        <div id="sunday-off"> - </div>
        <div id="monday-afternoon">12:00 - 15:59</div>
        <div id="tuesday-afternoon">12:00 - 15:59</div>
        <div id="wednesday-afternoon">12:00 - 15:59</div>
        <div id="thursday-afternoon">12:00 - 15:59</div>
        <div id="friday-afternoon">12:00 - 15:59</div>
        <div id="saturday-morning">06:00 - 08:59</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is use Javascript functions getDay() and getHours() + getMinutes() to show only the presenter that is scheduled to be on air based on the times specified in the app.

The main part I am having difficulty with is with determining whether this presenter falls within the current time and then showing/hiding the div as necessary.

Any help or guidance on how I can acheive this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What data are you using to create the divs. Is it a json object, an array?

Comment: @Bruno I am building on Adobe's Business Catalyst. So what I have done is built a Web App (mini database of sorts) that stores the data and displays based on styling and code that I specify.

Answer (score 2):

You can just compare with the getHours and getDay function as follows, you don't have to worry about the minutes function as they all sit on the boundaries of hours. Just remember that day is 0 indexed from Sunday

```
//Hide all the divs up here
var d = new Date();
var weekday = d.getDay();
var hours = d.getHours();
//    between 12 and 6pm           From monday  to friday
if (hours >= 12 && hours < 18 && weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {
   switch(weekday) {
      case 1:
          //Show monday
          break;
      case 2:
          //Show tuesday
          break;
      case 3:
          //Show wed
          break;
      case 4:
          //Show thur
          break;
      case 5:
          //Show fri
          break;
    }
//          Saturday         between 6 and 9
} else if (weekday == 6 && hours >=6 && hours < 9) {
  //Show saturday
} else if (weekday == 0) {
  //Show sunday
}
```

Edit: as per your request heres a simple modular implementation

```
var schedule = [
    {"starthour":12, "endhour":18, "weekday":1, "div":"div1"},
    {"starthour":18, "endhour":20, "weekday":1, "div":"div2"}
]
var d = new Date();
var weekday = d.getDay();
var hours = d.getHours();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++) {
    if (schedule[i].starthour >= hours && schedule[i].endhour < hours && schedule[i].weekday == weekday) {
        //Show schedule[i].div
    }
}
```

Comment: This is getting to close what I need. My only question is what if the slot changes? I have to go through and updated my JS. Is there a way to use the Days and Hours specified in the app to prevent this kind of maintenance?

Comment: @PetaReardon—you could have a separate object to store days and hours, but then the logic becomes more complex too. It depends on whether the added complexity of the code pays back in easier maintenance and ongoing use.

Comment: Pretty much what RobG said. Depends if the slots are going to change a lot and if there are more values than what is described. You could make a generic case where you pass in a js array that just contains the weekday, hours and div, and loop through it to test whether that div should be shown at this time. I'll put an edit demonstrating this.

Comment: @RobG I currently have 5 presenters, and am going to have a couple more. There are 24 slots each week and some land of the half hour. Because I am building it for someone else it would ideally pick up the hours from the app so that they can update the fields themselves and not have to come back to me if a staff memeber leaves or if a new slot is created. This all seemed much simpler in my mind in that there would be a way to say that today = Thursday and match that to those who have thursday slots and time = 9:38 which falls between times for the morning slot.

Comment: @RobG Because my JS isn't the best can you give me a brief run-down of how the modular implementation works? Thanks

Comment: Just have some logic to retrieve a json array containing json objects similar to the schedules array above. Then iterate through the array and see whether the current time is within the start/finish time/day of each item of the array. If it is, show a certain div. I can't really make it any simpler.....

Answer (score 0):

If you already are using jQuery library. I'll suggest you use a date library for easier to read code and a bit more maintainable too
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

```
timenow = $.format.date( new Date(), 'ddd h:mm a')
// returns Monday 6:22 AM

switch(timenow){
case 'Monday 1:00 PM':
    //do something
    break;
case 'Tuesday 3:00 PM':
    //do something
    break;
}
```

then if it's always within the hour, just ommit the minutes. use the format **'ddd h a'**
So you could write your JavaScript with a SWITCH

```
timenow = $.format.date( new Date(), 'ddd h a')
// returns Monday 6 AM

switch(timenow){
case 'Monday 1 PM':
case 'Monday 2 PM':
    //do something
    break;
case 'Tuesday 3 PM':
    //do something
    break;
}
```

but if you're not using jquery, and you want to just use getDay(), plain javascript

```
var days =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var d = new Date();
var hr = d.getHours() % 12;

timenow = days[d.getDay()] + ' ' + hr + (d.getHours() > 12?'PM':'AM')

// returns "Monday 2PM"
```

things to note: to fetch your current presenters via AJAX to handle the DB

Comment: I don't think that helps the OP at all. Why introduce 2 libraries when none is required?

Comment: I'm trying to suggest some simple way, so he could manage it quicker with switch case

Comment: Simpler than `new Date().getDay()`?