# How to schedule a div display with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a `div id="button"` I want to display from 9am to 19pm on work days (Monday to Friday).
When this `div` is not displayed ("else") I want to show a `div id="different"`.

I think I found a similar but more complex solution here [Show div based on getDay and getHours + getMinutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556126/show-div-based-on-getday-and-gethours-getminutes)

The problem is that I am a dummy in JS and can not follow. A simple and easy-to-adjust copy / paste solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's not really how SO works ... http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @JanHančič Why is this question bad? It's not a subjective question and it's asking for a definite solution. It's reasonably scoped and isn't asking for discussion. The OP does not provide code but does link to some and asks for something more appropriate for a beginner. Did I miss something in the FAQ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting the rules, but I think that "give me the code" type of questions are not welcomed here ...

Comment: @JanHančič Could be my misinterpretation. It's just I couldn't see anything explicitly wrong with this question and writing short bits of code for others which are easy for beginners to understand can be a good way for beginners to learn. On the other hand, if the question had said "Please do my homework" I'd probably be less forgiving ;-)

Comment: @JanHančič As you're someone with a high reputation and with an interest in good use of SO, I'd be interested to see what you think about the possible case of plagiarism below... Any thoughts on this or is this just something we have to accept and move on?

Comment: @JanHančič Thanks. I was thinking of doing that myself but I've never flagged before and didn't know if this was worth flagging... Is it worth me flagging it too, or is one enough?

Comment: I think it should be enough ...

Comment: What's wrong with the question again? They 90% are about "give me the code". Or should I have also inserted my js experiments and mark with "<- this doesn't work!" so you wouldn't have thought I am asking to do my homework for me? Or the question is too easy? Well, excuse me, we all have a different background. Or maybe it has no value? It does, I am getting this question like every week for the last x years, but I do a way different thing. And an answer can not be googled (easily at least) so it will definitely gain traffic and grateful (js newbie) audience.

Comment: @MarinaIvanchuk Agreed. I can understand where Jan is coming from (hence my joke about the homework) but I think your question shows some research and is pretty clearly asking for a solution, which is I think is a good use of Stack Overflow. I think it might also be a useful question for beginners, which is why I provided an answer below. I've only just realised that I hadn't upvoted the question before, but I will now, though unfortunately it will only bring it back to zero. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution:

```
var dt = new Date(); // get current date
var dy = dt.day(); // get the day from the date object
var hr = dt.getHours(); // get the hour from the date object

if (dy >= 1 && dy <= 5 && hr >= 9 && hr < 19) { // check the time is right
    document.getElementById('button').style.display = 'block'; // shows button as block
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none'; // hides "other" button.
} else {
    document.getElementById('button').style.display = 'none'; // shows button as block
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block'; // hides "other" button.
}
```

This very specifically does what you say but could be adapted with reference to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), which will give you the numbers for the days (Sunday is 0, Monday 1, etc.) and other properties of the JavaScript Date object if you need them.

[I'm sure others could play some [code golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) with it too.]

Comment: Thank you) I've also read some on w3schools and added it as getUTCDay and getUTCHours so display time would depend on my actual working hours, not visitor local time.